# specify db in gemfile rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubygems

I want to use `postgres` db for my local and production environment both.

How should my `gemfile` look like for this case?

Should I completely remove `sqlite` and just put `gem pg` or the development and production environment is required with `pg`?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In gemfile you only list the dependancies your application rely on. So, you don't *have* to remove `sqlite` from there, it really won't make any difference (but of corse it's better to remove it if you don't use it).

The place where you config your application which db to use is `database.yml`. You can find all the info here http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database.
In short, you should add following to your `database.yml`:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: blog_development
  pool: 5    
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: blog_production
  pool: 5
```

Comment: Ok, this is exactly how I have it. Thanks